# How to make ajax call with angular2/http?

Tags: http, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 with typescript. I was able to make ajax call with window['fetch'] out of the box without any problem (and I did not need to use any of the workarounds required in earlier versions.)

But I could not make the same ajax call working with angular2's http.

Here is the code to demo the issue. There are three files, index.html in the project folder, and boot.ts and app.component.ts in a subfolder called app.

app.component.ts:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><button (click)="getTasks()">click</button>{{tasks}}'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    http: Http;
    tasks = [];

    constructor(http: Http) {
        alert(http == null);
        this.http = http;
    }

    getTasks(): void {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/tasks/norender');
            //.map((res: Response) => res.json())

            //it is important to have this subscribe call, since the 
            //request is only made if there is a subscriber 
            .subscribe(res => this.tasks = res);
    }   
}
```

boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript', 
            typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true}, 
            packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What would be the problem/error?

Comment: Did you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in your bootstrap?

Comment: The way you tried is correct. I just noticed also that you are bootstraping in System.import. I haven't seen that way of doing it before, is that working for you? Can you try bootstraping in the same `SomeComponent` file? Remember to import `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from `angular2/http`.

Comment: For what I see in your updated code, you need to uncomment the `subscribe` since that's the part that triggers the request.

Comment: That was it! Thanks @EricMartinez, so it is smart and only makes the request if the result is consumed. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have HTTP_PROVIDERS in `bootstrap()` and in `providers: [...]`.  Pick one.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, you are right, I picked bootstrap() and that worked. Also I realized that it was not necessary for me to define my own http property, if I pass "public http: Http" to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add an Http provider. You have two options:

1. On bootstrap:

`import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';`

and:

```
ng.bootstrap(src.SomeComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

2. On the component using the service:

   import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

   @Component({

   ...

   providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

   ...
   })

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I used an old version of the TypeScript compiler. I fixed it by changing the constructor argument from `http: Http` to `@Inject(Http) http: Http`. Of course, you need to import `Inject` to use it.

I'd try using the SystemJS release at https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js instead of the release at rawgithub.com.